# PHP passing any class to one method of Trait and create new instance

Tags: php, laravel

In this simple `Trait` in `php` i would like to pass any class into `sample` method and when `$class` is null, it should be create new instance from that.

`sample` method of `Trait` is not correct and its only a pseudo code

```php
trait HasForm
{
    // ...

    public function sample(?Class $class = null)
    {
        $class = $class ?: new {$class}();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

this `Trait` should be used in more another class and only one thing is different here and thats `sample` method, simply i want to change below method to use that on each class which will want to it:

```php
public function sample(?Post $post = null): Form
{
    $post = $post ?: new Post();
    return $this->formBuilder->create(PostForm::class, [
        'model' => $post
    ]);
}
```

specifying class specific class which this is `Post` here cause of I'll have to had more method in this `Trait`. for example:

```php
trait HasForm
{
    // ...
    public function sample(?Post $post = null): Form
    {
        $post = $post ?: new Post();
        return $this->formBuilder->create(PostForm::class, [
            'model' => $post
        ]);
    }
    
    public function sample1(?Categories $categories = null): Form
    {
        $post = $post ?: new Categories();
        return $this->formBuilder->create(CategoriesForm::class, [
            'model' => $categories
        ]);
    }
    public function sample2(?Comments $comments = null): Form
    {
        $post = $post ?: new Comments();
        return $this->formBuilder->create(CommentsForm::class, [
            'model' => $comments
        ]);
    }
}
```

i try to know how can i combine them, because only class parameter id is different at all

Comment: create new instance of what if its null ?

Comment: @lagbox my post updated, please review again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
trait HasForm
{
    // ...

    public function sample($classname = null)
    {
        $classname = $classname ?: new $classname();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```